Total days on consecutive date records up to gap
I have a classic Gaps and Islands issue whereby I need to total the time across the most recent records as far back as the first gap in dates
Looking at Find Consecutive Date in SQL using 2 date columns, this provides a very neat solution to my question except that it does not work for sql server, there are syntax errors.
Does anyone have an equivalent solution that works for sql server?
The data is something like this



REF
TNCY-START
TNCY-END




1
2022-08-22
2024-04-22


1
2019-04-29
2022-08-21


1
2017-06-26
2019-04-28


1
2009-06-29
2010-01-31


2
2020-07-13
NULL


2
2020-05-18
2020-07-12


2
2020-01-13
2020-05-17


2
2010-12-06
2016-08-28


2
2003-09-29
2009-06-01


3
2019-03-25
NULL


4
2022-08-22
NULL


4
2019-04-29
2022-08-21


4
2017-06-26
2019-04-28


4
2009-06-29
2010-01-31



create table #test ([PERSON-REF] INT, 
                   [TNCY-START] DATE,
                   [TNCY-END] DATE);
INSERT INTO #test VALUES


('1', '2022-08-22 00:00:00.000',    '2024-04-22 00:00:00.000'),
('1',   '2019-04-29 00:00:00.000',  '2022-08-21 00:00:00.000'), 
('1',   '2017-06-26 00:00:00.000',  '2019-04-28 00:00:00.000'), 
('1',   '2009-06-29 00:00:00.000',  '2010-01-31 00:00:00.000'),
('2',   '2020-07-13 00:00:00.000',  null),
('2',   '2020-05-18 00:00:00.000',  '2020-07-12 00:00:00.000'),
('2',   '2020-01-13 00:00:00.000',  '2020-05-17 00:00:00.000'),
('2',   '2010-12-06 00:00:00.000',  '2016-08-28 00:00:00.000'),
('2',   '2003-09-29 00:00:00.000',  '2009-06-01 00:00:00.000'),
('3',   '2019-03-25 00:00:00.000',  NULL),
('4',   '2022-08-22 00:00:00.000',  NULL),
('4',   '2019-04-29 00:00:00.000',  '2022-08-21 00:00:00.000'),
('4',   '2017-06-26 00:00:00.000',  '2019-04-28 00:00:00.000'),
('4',   '2009-06-29 00:00:00.000',  '2010-01-31 00:00:00.000')

SELECT * FROM #test;


and I want to end up with a single row per person ref containing  person-ref, count of records after gap, start date after gap, latest end date (or null), days between.
eg assuming UK date format and taking null as today



REF
COUNT OF TENANCIES
FIRST TNCY-START
LAST TNCY-END
TOTAL TENANCY DAYS




1
3
2017-06-26
2024-04-22
2492


2
3
2020-01-13
NULL
1562


3
1
2019-03-25
NULL
1866


4
3
2017-06-26
NULL
2493



Thanks for any help anyone can offer

can you please share the wanted result?

You can self join table on dateadd(day,1,a.TNCY-END)=b.TNCY-START

WITH Boundaries
AS
(
    SELECT [PERSON-REF], [TNCY-START]
        ,COALESCE([TNCY-END], '9999') AS [TNCY-END]
        ,CASE
            WHEN [TNCY-END] IS NULL
            THEN 0
            WHEN COALESCE(LAG([TNCY-START]) OVER (PARTITION BY [PERSON-REF] ORDER BY [TNCY-START] DESC), DATEADD(day, 1, [TNCY-END])) = DATEADD(day, 1, [TNCY-END])
            THEN 0
            ELSE 1
        END AS Boundary
    FROM #test
)
,Grps
AS
(
    SELECT [PERSON-REF], [TNCY-START], [TNCY-END]
        ,SUM(Boundary) OVER (PARTITION BY [PERSON-REF] ORDER BY [TNCY-START] DESC) AS Grp
    FROM Boundaries
)
,Ranges
AS
(
    SELECT [PERSON-REF]
        ,COUNT(1) AS [COUNT_OF_TENANCIES]
        ,MIN([TNCY-START]) AS [FIRST_TNCY-START]
        ,NULLIF(MAX([TNCY-END]), '9999') AS [LAST_TNCY-END]
    FROM Grps
    WHERE Grp = 0
    GROUP BY [PERSON-REF]
)
SELECT [PERSON-REF], [COUNT_OF_TENANCIES], [FIRST_TNCY-START], [LAST_TNCY-END]
    ,DATEDIFF(day, [FIRST_TNCY-START], COALESCE([LAST_TNCY-END], CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)) AS [TOTAL_TENANCY_DAYS]
FROM Ranges;


This is great, working well for me thanks
